# How to build base64 image src with jsp source?

Tags: java, jsp, request, base64, inputstream

I am struggling with base64.

I would like to decode an image which comes though wysiwyg editor.

I build a source like below.(it is part of...)

```
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
byte b[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

String base64DataString = Base64.encodeBase64String(b);
String aaa = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(b);

base64DataString = "data:image/" + ext + ";base64," + aaa;
if(aaa == "a"){}

if(is != null) {
  is.close();
}
```

I got InputStream from request and make it as byte array.

size of byte[] b is exactly same with size of file I uploaded.

Then I combine a String to put src attribute of image tag.

After all of this when I look at in HTML. It has a broken image.

output looks like below :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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
" title="gaebul.jpeg">
```

What is the suspicious part of my code?

Thanks for sweet answer :D bb

Comment: I added `"data:image/" + ext + ";base64,"`, since wiki says. link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: got this. I just test over and over with this site http://base64online.org/decode/. I think the problem is `String aaa` part. I have replaced the aaa part of `base64DataString = "data:image/" + ext + ";base64," + aaa` with `base64DataString` itself. now it works fine :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be encoding two times without the real need, you should just do

```
byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(b);
String base64DataString = new String(encodeBase64 , "UTF-8");
```

and than just

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[the value of your base64DataString]"
```